# Condition number of matrix inversion with respect to spectral norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, condition-number, spectral-norm

I would like to show that "the condition number for inversion of $A$, with respect to the spectral norm is $k(A)=\rho(A)\rho(A^{-1})$" for $A\in M_n$ as nonsingular and normal matrix . Can anyone confirm the following proof:

By definition we have:

1. $\rho(A)=\max\{|\lambda|:\lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$. (spectral radius).
2. If $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$, then $Ax=\lambda x$.
3. $k(A)=|||A|||\:|||A^{-1}|||$ (condition number).
4. $|||A|||=\max_{||x||=1}||Ax||$ (induced matrix norm).

Now we can write:
\begin{gather}
  |||A|||=\max_{||x||=1}||Ax||=\max_{||x||=1}||\lambda x||=\rho(A), \\
  |||A^{-1}|||=\max_{||x||=1}||A^{-1}x||=\max_{||x||=1}||\lambda^{-1} x||=\rho(A^{-1}).
\end{gather}
So the condition number of $k(A)=|||A|||\:|||A^{-1}|||=\rho(A)\rho(A^{-1})$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment loup blanc. Do you mean the third statement for condition number? If so, this is the statement from Matrix Algebra book by Horn, first edition, page 336. So, what I concern is the replacement of $Ax$ with $\lambda x$ to reach the spectral norm. It would be great if you could be more specific.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Ax=\lambda x$ for *some* nonzero $x$, *not all* $x$. This makes both equations following "Now we can write" incorrect.

Comment: Actually this is one of the condition for the norm: 
||x||=0 IFF x=0 , and in the all equations there is a condition : ||x||=1. However, I can add the condition that x is nonzero. then  do you think the proof is OK? /thanks

Comment: Again: $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $x$ does not imply that $\max_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|=\max_{\|x\|=1}\|\lambda x\|$. The problem is not with "nonzero" but with "some $\neq$ all".

Comment: Yes you are right. Do you have any idea to prove that "the condition number for inversion of $A$, with respect to the spectral norm is $k(A)=\rho(A)\rho(A^{−1})$".

Comment: I don't because it's not true unless $A$ is real symmetric or complex Hermitian.

Comment: As I checked the Horn's book again, $A\in M_n$ is nonsingular and normal as well. I am just posting another answer which might be correct, please comment it if you think something is missing./thanks"

Comment: Well, for normal matrices it's true as well. But this just follows simply from the fact that absolute values of the eigenvalues of a normal matrix are exactly its singular values.

Answer (score 1):

taking the $Euclidea\: norm$ in to account defined for square-summable sequence space, then
\begin{equation*}
  k(A)= \frac{\sigma_{\max}(A)}{\sigma_{min}(A)}
 \end{equation*}
where $\sigma_{\max}(A)$ and $\sigma_{\min}(A)$ are maximal and minimal singular values of $A$. So, if $A$ is normal then
\begin{equation}\label{eq8_1}
  k(A)=|\frac{\lambda_{\max}(A)}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}|.
\end{equation}
On the other hand,
\begin{equation}\label{eq8_2}
  \rho(A)=\max\{|\lambda|:\lambda \in \sigma(A)\}=\lambda_{\max}(A)
\end{equation}
and if $A$ is invertible and have $\lambda$ as eigenvalue the $A^{-1}$ has the eigenvalue of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, so we have
\begin{equation}\label{eq8_3}
  \lambda_{\min}(A)=\frac{1}{\lambda_{\max}(A^{-1})} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}=\lambda_{\max}(A^{-1})=\rho(A^{-1})
\end{equation}
Now substituting (\ref{eq8_3}) and (\ref{eq8_2}) in (\ref{eq8_1}) yields
\begin{equation*}
  k(A)=|\frac{\lambda_{\max}(A)}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}|=\rho(A)\rho(A^{-1}).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Arry, your original question concerns any matrix, and without supplementary hypothesis, your result is false. Now you consider a normal matrix and, using the Roger's book, you present a correct result. Yet, the eigenvectors of a generic normal matrix are pairwise orthogonal ; that implies that a randomly chosen matrix is "never" normal.

Comment: Now I've edited the question and added supplementary hypothesis. but still it would be good to prove the first statement: $k(A)=|\frac{\sigma_{max}(A)}{\sigma_{min}(A)}|$

Answer (score 0):

If $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a normal matrix then $$\kappa_2(\boldsymbol{A})=\frac{\operatorname{máx}_{\lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A})}|\lambda|}{\operatorname{mín}_{\lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A})}|\lambda|}$$
but if the matrix $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is only no singular and $||\cdot||$ a subordinate matrix norm for the book introduction to numerical algebra and optimisation by philippe ciarlet, the $\textbf{theorem 1.4-3}$ part 1.
$$\rho(\boldsymbol{A})\leq ||\boldsymbol{A}||$$ and this proof is the same to $\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}$, i.e.
if $(\lambda, \boldsymbol{v})$ is an autopar $\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}$. This means that $\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{v}=\frac{1}{\lambda }\boldsymbol{v}$. It is known to exist $ \boldsymbol{w} \in \mathbb{C}^n \backslash\{\mathbf{0}\}$ such that $ \boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{w}^* \neq \boldsymbol{\Theta}$ (is easy to check). then

\begin{align*}
\left(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1} \boldsymbol{v}\right) \boldsymbol{w}^*
=\left(\frac{1}{\lambda } \boldsymbol{v}\right) \boldsymbol{w}^* 
 &\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\lambda }\left(\boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{w}^*\right)
=\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\left(\boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{w}^*\right) \\
&\Rightarrow\left\|\frac{1}{\lambda }\left(\boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{w}^*\right)\right\|
=\left\|\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\left(\boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{w}^*\right)\right\| 
\leq\|\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\| \| \boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{w}^* \| \\
& \Rightarrow \left|\frac{1}{\lambda }\right| \| \boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{w}^*\|\leq\| \boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\|\| \boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{w}^*\| \\
&\Rightarrow\left|\frac{1}{\lambda }\right| \leq\| \boldsymbol{A}^{-1} \| 
\end{align*}

In this way for all $ \lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1})$ it has to $\left|\frac{1}{\lambda }\right |||\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}||$, which is equivalent to say
\begin{equation}
    \rho(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}) \leq\|\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\|
\end{equation}
So of the inequalities it has to

\begin{equation}
   \rho(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}) \rho(\boldsymbol{A}) \leq ||\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}|| ||\boldsymbol{A}||
\end{equation}
Finally, from the definition of the spectral radius it follows that
\begin{align*}
\|\boldsymbol{A}\| &= \rho(\boldsymbol{A})=\max_{\lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A})} |\lambda| \\
\left\|\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\right\| 
&=\rho\left(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\right)=\max_{\lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A})} \frac{1}{|\lambda|}=\frac{1}{\min_{\lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A})}|\lambda|}
\end{align*}
by replacing in the above equation
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{\min_{\lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A})}|\lambda|} \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A})} |\lambda|  =\rho(\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}) \rho(\boldsymbol{A}) \leq \kappa(\boldsymbol{A})
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{equation*}
\kappa(\boldsymbol{A}) \geq \frac{\max _{\lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A})}|\lambda|}{\min _{\lambda \in \sigma(\boldsymbol{A})}|\lambda|}
\end{equation*}